# Не могу загрузить файлы на сервер

Tags: файлы, php, загрузка, сервер

Здравствуйте, уважаемое сообщество.
Возникла проблема следующего типа: написал простенький скрипт загрузки файла не сервер -

```
<?php
    if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] > 0) {
        echo 'Проблема: ';
        switch ($_FILES['userfile']['error']) {
            case 1: echo 'Размер файла больше upload_max_filesize';
                break;
            case 2: echo 'Размер файла больше max_file_size';
                break;
            case 3: echo 'Загружена только часть файла';
                break;
            case 4: echo 'Файл не загружен';
                break;
            case 6: echo 'Загрузка невозможна: не задан временный каталог';
                break;
            case 7: echo 'Загрузка не выполнена: невозможна запись на диск';
                break;
        }
        exit;
    }
//Проверка, имеет ли файл правильный MIME-тип
if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != 'text/plain') {
    echo 'Проблема: файл не является текстовым';
    exit;
}
//Помещаем файл в нужный каталог
$upfile = '/php-edu/upload/FILE_FOLDER/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $upfile)) {
        echo 'Проблема. Невозможно поместить файл в каталог назначения';
        exit;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Проблема: возможна атака через загрузку файла. Файл: '.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
}
echo 'Файл успешно загружен в папку. <br /><br />';

//Удаление возможных дескрипторов из соержимого файла
$contents = file_get_contents($upfile);
$contents = strip_tags($contents);
file_put_contents($_FILES['userfile']['name'], $contents);

//Вывод загруженого файла
echo 'Предварительный просмотр загруженого файла: <br /><br />';
echo nl2br($contents);
echo '<br /><hr />';
?>
```

Клиентская часть:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">
    <label>Выгрузить файл на сервер</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile"><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Выгрузить!">
</form>
```

Но файл не загружается на сервер. Обработка останавливается на ошибке **Проблема. Невозможно поместить файл в каталог назначения**.

Использую Ubuntu 13.04, права на папки и на сам скрипт выставил. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема. Спасибо.

Comment: Значит путь не правильно указан. Попробуйте дописать:

    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$upfile)) {
        // ...
    }

Comment: Да, сработало, спасибо.
Только, если позволите, еще вопрос - файл загружается в два места - в указанную в скрипте папку, и в корень папки upload (на уровень выше). Кроме того, информация из файла не читается. Не смотря на то, что права на папку я выставил 777, файлы все-равно почему-то закрыты для чтения.

Comment: Не очень уверен, но похоже, что две проблемы имеют одни корни. Считываете файл из одного источника, а записываете обработанный результат в другой. Может всё-таки так:

    $contents = file_get_contents($upfile);
    $contents = strip_tags($contents);
    file_put_contents($upfile, $contents);

Comment: Файл теперь кладет в нужную папку, а вот читать не хочет. В общем - спасибо) Дальше буду уже мучить Убунту.

Comment: > ... а вот читать не хочет ...

Вы уверены в этом? )) Сделайте проверку:

    $contents = file_get_contents($upfile);
    if($contents){
       echo 'Гуд';
    } else {
       echo 'Лажа';
    }

Comment: Лажа получилась)

Comment: @Богдан Остапчук, значит опять можно поднять вопрос о правильности указанного пути к файлу.

Comment: Все, вопрос решил, действительно проблемы с путями - моя оплошность. Спасибо, что наставили на путь истинный)

Answer (score 2):

попробуй дать права для папки

```
sudo chmod 777 ***/php-edu/upload/FILE_FOLDER/
```

*** - заменить на конкретный путь